# http Apache Basic Authentication - What is more efficient?

Tags: http, authentication

Is it more efficient on basic auth to use:

```
require group abc
```

or

```
require user bob, jill, fred, pam, etc
```

where the group flat file contains the valid usernames?

Or does it not matter?

I am looking for an easy way to manage an extensive list of valid users for http authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If different users have different privileges, groups will be much easier to manage instead of editing all related configuration files everytime a user is added.

However, if all users have the same privileges, you don't need to require any specific user or group, you could just go with [`require valid-user`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#require) so that any user is allowed access to the resource.